# Using named nodes as pgfplots coordinates

Tags: pgfplots, boxplot

Is it possible to use named nodes as coordinates in an `\addplot` command?

I am trying to plot a line through the averages of a number of boxplots calculated by `pgfplots` (rather than using `boxplot prepared`). My naive idea of naming the average nodes and using them as input coordinates in a separate `\addplot` command in the MWE below throws an error. Unfortunately, just using `tikz` to plot the line seems to not properly connect the line segments, and I would have to define a separate line style for `tikz` that I have already defined for `pgfplots`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}

\begin{document}
  \pgfplotstableread{
    A   B   C
    5   2   1
    2   3   6
    1   4   5
    2   5   4
    1   6   6
    7   5   2
    3   6   4
  }{\datatable}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        [boxplot/draw direction=y, 
         boxplot/average=auto, boxplot/every average/.style={mark=},
         ytick={1,3,...,9}, xtick={1,2,3}, xticklabels={A, B, C}
        ]
      \addplot+[boxplot] table[y=A]\datatable node (A) at (boxplot box cs: \boxplotvalue{average}, 0.5) {};
      \addplot+[boxplot] table[y=B]\datatable node (B) at (boxplot box cs: \boxplotvalue{average}, 0.5) {};
      \addplot+[boxplot] table[y=C]\datatable node (C) at (boxplot box cs: \boxplotvalue{average}, 0.5) {};

      \draw [ultra thick, red] (A) -- (B) -- (C);
      %\addplot[ultra thick, red] coordinates { (A) (B) (C) }; 
      % Runaway argument? A) (B) (C) \pgfplots@EOI \pgfplotsscanlinelengthcleanup \pgfplots@coord@stream@ end \ETC.
      % ! File ended while scanning use of \pgfplots@foreach@plot@coord@NEXT@.
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: The output from the MWE]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `coordinate (..) at (...);` instead of `node (..) at (...) {};`, then the `\draw` works as expected. Another way is to change to `\draw (A.center) -- (B.center) -- (C.center);` while using `node`, then lines are drawn between the centers of the nodes, rather than edge to edge, as is the default.

If you've defined a style in the `axis` options or with `\pgfplotsset` then you can apply this in a `\draw` by using `/pgfplots/stylename`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}

\begin{document}
  \pgfplotstableread{
    A   B   C
    5   2   1
    2   3   6
    1   4   5
    2   5   4
    1   6   6
    7   5   2
    3   6   4
  }{\datatable}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        [boxplot/draw direction=y, 
         boxplot/average=auto, boxplot/every average/.style={mark=},
         ytick={1,3,...,9}, xtick={1,2,3}, xticklabels={A, B, C},
         someline/.style={ultra thick,red}
        ]
      \addplot+[boxplot] table[y=A]\datatable coordinate (A) at (boxplot box cs: \boxplotvalue{average}, 0.5);
      \addplot+[boxplot] table[y=B]\datatable coordinate (B) at (boxplot box cs: \boxplotvalue{average}, 0.5);
      \addplot+[boxplot] table[y=C]\datatable coordinate (C) at (boxplot box cs: \boxplotvalue{average}, 0.5);

      \draw [/pgfplots/someline] (A) -- (B) -- (C);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works great. If there is an answer in the next few days that manages to use `\addplot`, I'd prefer it (because of the duplicate style issue). Otherwise, I'll accept this one.

Comment: @ThomasH Does the additional info I added help in that respect?

Comment: Yes, it does. I feel a bit stupid now for not having thought of referencing the style via `/pgfplots/` myself ... I'll wait another day or so to accept. If there's no answer addressing the question in the title, I'll accept yours and probably change the title to something more reflective of the question body and your answer.